# C# - optimize logic

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq

I have a list of object. Those objects contain lat and lon coordinates among other properties. I want to extract only thoose coordonates that satisfy

```
(Math.Abs(elem1.lat - elem2.lat) > Delta && Math.Abs(elem1.lon - elem2.lon) > Delta)
```

Basically I want to extract only objects that dont have coordinates close to each other.

Is there an elegant way to do this with C# LINQ ?

> EDIT 1 :

So elem1 and elem2 are any 2 elements from the list. I elements that will result from the query to have more then delta between any 2 of them

> EDIT 2 :

This is my code at the moment. It works as I want :

```
for (int i = 0; i < companyHistory.Count; i++)
{
     var isOk = true;
     var count = zoomApprovedHistory.Count;
     for (var j = 0; j < count; j++)
     {
          if (Math.Abs(companyHistory[i].X - zoomApprovedHistory[j].X) < delta && Math.Abs(companyHistory[i].Y - zoomApprovedHistory[j].Y) < delta)
           {
                  isOk = false;
                  break;
            }
     }

      // if no other point is close add it to approved array for this zoom
      if (isOk)
        {
          zoomApprovedHistory.Add(companyHistory[i]);
         }
}
```

> How can I optimize it ? it has O(n^2) complexity. Looking for the fastest option

Comment: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/12/01/k-means-data-clustering-using-c.aspx

Comment: What's your elem1 and elem2? If those are any two elements in the list your question needs refining. Think about it; two objects may not fit your criteria, but one of those two objects, say elem2, might fit the criteria with another different element. Do you pick elem2 or not?

Comment: You say "all elem", but then you show an example showing what looks like 2 different elements, please explain more/better what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Your equation shows elements that *are* close to each other, but your question states you want elements that *aren't*.  Do you want elements that are near *every* other element, elements that are near *at least one* other element, elements that are far from every other element, or elements that are far from at least one other element?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Suppose you have these lons `10.0 10.2 10.4 10.6 10.8 11.0` with all same lats and delta=0.3, Do you want to remove all items?(item *n* is too close to item *n+1*)
or Is `10.0 10.4 10.8` a solution? Or Is `10.2 10.6 11.0` another solution? Or Are you satisfied with only `10.0 and 11.0`? Why? Unclear what you are asking?

Comment: So any 2 pint from the array need to be further then delta. I want this because I dont want markers to overlap on map

Comment: @Zodiac You still haven't answered my questions. Given the example coordinates above, what is the correct answer?

Comment: Both are correct for delta 0.3 : 10.0 10.4 10.8 ,  10.2 10.6 11.0 . It doesn't matter witch solutions returns out of those 2.

Comment: In fact, what you are looking for is *clustering* as in my very first comment. 1 marker for each cluster. See this javascript example https://asmaloney.com/2015/06/code/clustering-markers-on-leaflet-maps/

Comment: A good example of [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not well-phrased. If your `elem1` or `elem2` is a single item you want to compare against, this is pretty easy. Just do a LINQ `Where` to find the items that match the criteria.

```
Coordinates it = new Coordinates { lat = 5, lon = 5 };
var picked = list.Where(x => Math.Abs(x.lat - it.lat) < Delta && Math.Abs(x.lon - it.lon) < Delta);
```

If, on the other hand, your two elements are any two elements in the list, then you run into a problem where you need to clarify things. As I mentioned in my comment, if your have `elem1`, `elem2`, and `elem3`, and if the first two don't match the criteria but if `elem2` and `elem3` do match the criteria, then are both of those elements (2 and 3) 'hits'? Assuming they are, the solution below will work. I wrote a simple Comparer to help make things easy as well.

```
public class CoordinateComparer : IEqualityComparer<Coordinates>
{
    public bool Equals(Coordinates x, Coordinates y)
    {
        return (x.lat == y.lat && x.lon == y.lon);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Coordinates obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;
            if (obj != null)
            {
                hash = hash * 23 + obj.lat.GetHashCode();
                hash = hash * 23 + obj.lon.GetHashCode();
            }
            return hash;
        }
    }
}

public class Coordinates
{
    public int lat { get; set; }
    public int lon { get; set; }
}

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Coordinates> list = new List<Coordinates>();
        list.Add(new Coordinates { lat = 5, lon = 4 }); 
        list.Add(new Coordinates { lat = 4, lon = 5 });
        list.Add(new Coordinates { lat = 7, lon = 4 });
        list.Add(new Coordinates { lat = 6, lon = 3 });
        list.Add(new Coordinates { lat = 8, lon = 2 });

        double Delta = 1.1;

        List<Coordinates> results = new List<Coordinates>();
        foreach(Coordinates item in list)
        {
            // Find items that match the condition
            var matches = list.Where(x => Math.Abs(x.lat - item.lat) < Delta && Math.Abs(x.lon - item.lon) < Delta);
            // The 'item' will always match the condition with itself, which is undesirable, so remove it
            matches = matches.Except(new List<Coordinates> { item }, new CoordinateComparer());
            // Add the items that are not already in it to the results list
            results.AddRange(matches.Where(x => !results.Contains(x, new CoordinateComparer())));
        }

        foreach (Coordinates item in results)
            Console.WriteLine("Lat : {0}, Lon : {1}", item.lat, item.lon);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }   
}
```

Bear in mind that if your latitude and longitude coordinates are either `double` or `float`, which they probably are, you might run into problems when comparing. But that's an altogether different question.

Comment: @downvoter why? Care to explain first?

Comment: My guess is OP downvoted your answer to the vague question because it wasn't the exact answer vaguely desired, as same thing happened to me.  I upvoted to offset.

Comment: @DaxFohl I hope that's not true because that's just silly. The question itself is _very_ ambiguous and so answer being not what's expected is not a reason for a downvote.

Comment: @DaxFohl the OP can't downvote (they don't have enough rep).  My guess you and Sach were downvoted for taking a guess in order to answer a vague and unclear question

Comment: OMG,of course I did not down voted youre  answer